# Passing primitive types to a Bundle

Tags: android

When i use Intent.putExtra to a Bundle to pass a int value, is that primitive bumped up to an Object first. I though only Parceable or Serializable objects could be passed to a Bundle. How about primitives. Is this bumped up to an Integer ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Internally Bundle uses `HashMap<String, Object>();`

see here 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/os/Bundle.java#Bundle.0mMap

Answer (score -1):

You can pass primitives types of variables with the intent or Bundle without making it parcelable or serializable.

When you will have to pass your custom object then you require to make it parcelable or Serializable. Parcelable is the best choice for Android.